# Weird mathematical issue using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi all javascript experts,
As I was studying some javascript, I came across some weird result from a simple subtraction.

```
4320 - 234  === 4086
8320 - 238  === 8082
8320 - 0238 === 8082
```

so far all normal , but if I input

```
4320 - 0234 === 4164
```

I am supposed to get 4086 but instead I get 4164.
Can someone explain?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Numbers starting with 0 are octals.

Comment: 0238 wasn't considered octal because it's not a valid octal number, while 0234 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers in javascript can start with a zero (0) followed by another decimal digit, but if every digit after the leading 0 is smaller than 8, the number gets parsed as an octal number.
[For more information visit the MDN web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates)

An octal number is a number whose base is 8 (0-7), like for binary the base is 2 (0-1). In your case:

234 =>  2*(8^2) + 3*(8^1) + 4*(8^0) = 128 + 24 + 4 =156